# How to handle orientation exactly like Youtube's Android App?

Tags: android, youtube

To handle orientation exactly like youtube android app I've following obstacles.

1. Once orientation is changed using `setRequestedOriention()` and set `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT` then `onConfigurationChanged()` is not getting called.
2. I've tried orientation event listener but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I think other than youtube, no other app has implemented this so far.

If anyone has any solution other than using `OrientationEventListener`, please let me know.